# Missing Mist and Z in render layers

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, depth-of-field

I'm Really Confused, There is no Z and Mist under Render layers, I tried clicking what I could and still no clue why they are not there. I'm trying to put mist in the Simulation.[image: There is no Mist and Z in Render Layers, and i have No Clue]

Comment: You need to enable those render passes in the renderlayer settings.

Comment: Z pass is Depth pass now. Mist must be enabled to be available in the nodes and this depends on render engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mist and Z for the view layer.

[image]

For older versions of blender (2.79 or previous)

[image]
On the Scene tab(yellow circle), make sure that Z and Mist are checked(red circle).
Also, make sure that the render layer in the Scene tab matches the render layer in the node editor (green circle).

**Z** is now called **Depth**.